# How to delegate to another function?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a function that delegates to another function, adding some logic before.

For a start, I tried creating a function that simply redirects to the `ADDDATE` mysql function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS custom_function(thedate DATE, days INTEGER) RETURNS DATE
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    return (select ADDDATE(thedate, days));
END
```

Result:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
        your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

What is wrong here? The error message isn't really helpful...

Comment: You have to create a function by first changing the default delimiter used by the client, then creating the function, and finally resetting the delimiter back to `;`, see [create-procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) for an example of how to create a function (and a procedure).

Comment: The function `hello` defined in the docs is defined without using `BEGIN` and `END` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` is not part of writing a `FUNCTION`.  The `BEGIN` and `END` are optional if the function can be expressed as simply `RETURN <<expression>>`.

The "Delimiter" stuff is needed at least when using the commandline "mysql" program.  If you are using some other UI, its use may be different.

Creating the function:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS custom_function(thedate DATE, days INTEGER) RETURNS DATE
    DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN ADDDATE(thedate, days);
//
DELIMITER ;
```

A sample use:

```
SELECT custom_function(CURDATE(), 5);
```

The result:

```
+-------------------------------+
| custom_function(CURDATE(), 5) |
+-------------------------------+
| 2022-08-20                    |
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: With this example the `DELIMITER` (change) is not needed. This is because the definition of the function does not have a semi-colon in  its definition.

Comment: @Luuk - Fine.  But it is good to get in the habit of using `DELIMITER`.  I probably should have mentioned that `BEGIN` and `END` are optional in this 'simple' case.

Comment: Indeed it's a good habit to always use  `DELIMITER`. But in this case the example in the question was (almost) begging to make clear that this edge-case does exist.... 